# Installing shiny server on Debian VM

Tags: r, ubuntu, debian, shiny-server

I was trying to host shiny app on an offline Debian VM. So, first, I install R-version 3.1.1 with apt-get on the VM:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install r-base
$ sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

Then, I scp all tar.gz files (Including all dependencies) of "shiny" package to the VM from my local and install them successfully with "R CMD ...". After that, I ran the following command to install "gdebi" and used it to install "shiny-server-1.3.0.403-amd64.deb" for shiny server.

```
$ sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
$ sudo gdebi shiny-server-1.3.0.403-amd64.deb
```

It returned error at the first time indicating the missing of dependencies:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Building data structures... Done 
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libssl0.9.8
```

Then, I followed another post to add the following line to the "etc/apt/sources.list" file and then install the missing dependencies with "apt-get":

```
 deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main

 $ sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 The following NEW packages will be installed:
 libssl0.9.8
 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded.
 Need to get 988 kB of archives.
 After this operation, 2,408 kB of additional disk space will be used.
 WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
 libssl0.9.8
 Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
 Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/main libssl0.9.8 amd64 0.9.8k-7ubuntu8.27 [988 kB]
 Fetched 988 kB in 1s (902 kB/s)      
 Preconfiguring packages ...
 Selecting previously unselected package libssl0.9.8.
 (Reading database ... 46468 files and directories currently installed.)
 Preparing to unpack .../libssl0.9.8_0.9.8k-7ubuntu8.27_amd64.deb ...
 Unpacking libssl0.9.8 (0.9.8k-7ubuntu8.27) ...
 Setting up libssl0.9.8 (0.9.8k-7ubuntu8.27) ...
 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u3) ...
```

It seems worked and I installed "shiny-server-1.3.0.403-amd64.deb":

```
$ sudo gdebi shiny-server-1.3.0.403-amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Building data structures... Done 

Shiny Server
Shiny Server is a server program from RStudio, Inc. that makes Shiny applications available over the web. Shiny is a web application framework for the R statistical computation language.
Do you want to install the software package? [y/N]:y
Selecting previously unselected package shiny-server.
(Reading database ... 46487 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack shiny-server-1.3.0.403-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking shiny-server (1.3.0.403) ...
Setting up shiny-server (1.3.0.403) ...
Creating user shiny
grep: /etc/init/shiny-server.conf: No such file or directory
Adding LANG to /etc/init.d/shiny-server, setting to en_US.UTF-8
```

Yet, when I tried to "stop/start" shiny server from terminal, cli can't recognize the command:

```
$ sudo stop shiny-server
sudo: stop: command not found
```

I am wondering whether I installed the server right? How can I "start/stop" shiny-server?

Comment: It looks like you've missed a few steps in the process. Since you're running Debian, you'll need to follow the instructions here: <https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/wiki/Building-Shiny-Server-from-Source> . I haven't yet set up a working shiny server myself, but this document sits in my files with the intention of doing it soon :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to get that link working properly, you might need to click the link "Building Shiny Server from source" on the right.

Comment: @rosscova thank you for sending all the instruction! Yet, I was following the instruction in https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/ which should be up-to-date, right? I used to make the server running on a EC2 with the step above. Yet, I feel it might because I install shiny package offline with "R CMD..." only which didn't install Shiny in system-wide library like "sudo su - -c "R -e \\"install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\\"" does?

Comment: Those instructions you're following are for a few specific operating systems, of which Debian is not one. You can switch to using one of the supported operating systems, or you can "build shiny server from source". The latter is what's described at the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Gotcha @rosscova ! I guess building shiny server from source is the option since I can't choose OS freely.:) Yet, before I try it, I did another tweak on my previous solution in which I reinstalled "shiny" package and its dependencies on a system-wide library on "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/" and start the server with "$ sudo systemctl start shiny-server". It seems work and returns followings when I checked the status: shiny-server.service - LSB: shiny Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/shiny-server)
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2016-04-30 12:53:16 PDT; 18h ago.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using shiny-server this way on Debian Wheezy but switched to self-compiling when I upgraded to Debian Jessie, since this was the recommended route per RStudio Documentation.

To answer your problem, shiny-server is managed using a init.d script. To start the server you should run `/etc/init.d/shiny-server start` or `service shiny-server start` as root (sudo).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Shiny problem, just you are missing the command , stop is an option for the command [service](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd)

You should use:

```
sudo service start shiny-server
```

to start it

```
sudo service stop shiny-server
```

to stop it